# Go validator with sql null types?

Tags: sql, validation, go

I am having problems getting the golang validator to work with SQL null types.  Here's an example of what I tried:

```golang
package main

import (
    "database/sql"
    "database/sql/driver"
    "log"

    "gopkg.in/go-playground/validator.v9"
)

// NullInt64
type NullInt64 struct {
    sql.NullInt64
    Set bool
}

func MakeNullInt64(valid bool, val int64) NullInt64 {
    n := NullInt64{}
    n.Set = true
    n.Valid = valid
    if valid {
        n.Int64 = val
    }
    return n
}
func (n *NullInt64) Value() (driver.Value, error) {
    if !n.NullInt64.Valid {
        return nil, nil
    }
    return n.NullInt64.Int64, nil
}

type Thing struct {
    N2 NullInt64 `validate:"min=10"`
    N3 int64     `validate:"min=10"`
    N4 *int64    `validate:"min=10"`
}

func main() {
    validate := validator.New()

    n := int64(6)
    number := MakeNullInt64(true, n)
    thing := Thing{number, n, &n}
    e := validate.Struct(thing)

    log.Println(e)
}
```

When I run this code, I only get this output:

> Key: 'Thing.N3' Error:Field validation for 'N3' failed on the 'min'
>   tag
>
> Key: 'Thing.N4' Error:Field validation for 'N4' failed on the
>   'min' tag

The problem is that I want it to also show that `Thing.N2` failed for the same reasons as `Thing.N3` and `Thing.N4`.

I tried introducing the `func (n *NullInt64) Value()` method because it was mentioned in the [documentation](https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/go-playground/validator.v9).  But I think I misunderstood something.  Can anyone tell me what I did wrong?

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**

There is an [Example](https://github.com/go-playground/validator/blob/v9/_examples/custom/main.go) specifically for that. You may check it out. My other proposed solution should still work though.

---

Since the value you are trying to validate is `Int64` inside `sql.NullInt64`, the easiest way would be to remove the `validate` tag and just register a [Struct Level](https://github.com/go-playground/validator/blob/v9/_examples/struct-level/main.go) validation using:

```golang
validate.RegisterStructValidation(NullInt64StructLevelValidation, NullInt64{})
```

while `NullInt64StructLevelValidation` is a `StructLevelFunc` that looks like this:

```golang
func NullInt64StructLevelValidation(sl validator.StructLevel) {
    ni := sl.Current().Interface().(NullInt64)
    if ni.NullInt64.Int64 < 10 {
        sl.ReportError(ni.NullInt64.Int64, "Int64", "", "min", "")
    }
}
```

Note #1: this line `thing := Thing{number,&number,n,&n}` has one argument too many. I assume you meant `thing := Thing{number, n, &n}`

Note #2: Go tooling including [gofmt](https://golang.org/cmd/gofmt/) is considered to be one of the most powerful features of the language. Please consider using it/[them](https://dev.to/plutov/go-tools-are-awesome-bom).

**EDIT #1:**
I don't think implementing `Valuer` interface is of any value in this context.